# Pydot creates graph with empty node next to root node

Tags: python, pydot

I'm trying to create an image of a decision tree using the pydot function graph_from_dot_data. Everything works fine, but the resulting image has an empty node next to the root node. Reproducible example -

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
import pydot
from IPython.display import Image

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
iris = load_iris()

clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
graph = graph_from_dot_data(export_graphviz(clf))

Image(graph[0].create_png())
```

[image]

How can I produce a decision tree image without an empty node next to the root node?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find empty node in small tree like:

```
for n in graph.get_nodes():
    print(n)
```

I have an empty node called `'"\\n"'`.
After that you can remove empty node by name:

```
graph.del_node('"\\n"')
```